# What's the subtle difference between competitiveness and competition

Tags: differences, vocabulary

What's the subtle difference between competitiveness and competition.
is there any differences? I couldn't find any information on google.

competitiveness:  an aggressive willingness to compete

competition:

. The act of competing, as for profit or a prize; rivalry.
2. A test of skill or ability; a contest: a skating competition.
3. Rivalry between two or more businesses striving for the same customer or market.

am using freedictionary site.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the dictionary definitions of both of these words. Make sure to name the dictionary you're quoting. Then elaborate on any questions you have remaining about the differences.

Comment: I don't think the difference is particularly subtle, the definitions in your own post are quite distinct. *competitiveness* is the desire to compete, *competition* is what you do to actually compete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Competitiveness** is a noun to describe the quality of being competitive. Competitive can mean either

## 1 being eager to compete, or

## 2 being able to compete well with one's opponents.

For example, a baseball team with the second-best record in its league or division is said to be "competitive"; they are "in the running" for that year's championship.

On the other hand, the **cellar-dwellers** might be so many games behind that they have no chance to become the champions of their league, so although they may be "competitive" in the first sense, they are not "competitive" in the second sense.

The noun for a person who competes is **competitor**.

A **competition** (countable noun) is an event (e.g. a sports game or a car race) in which competitors compete with one another.

**Competition** (uncountable noun) is what occurs in an environment (e.g. a workplace) that tends to set people in opposition to one another. See, for example, these lyrics.
http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/boston/peaceofmind.html